# Parse from JSON html string in Swift 2.3

Tags: json, xcode, swift2

My data below is printing HTML tags

```
let usernameRAW = json["username"] as? String
self.username = (usernameRAW)!
print("Username: \(self.username )")
```

It's showing some HTML tags from JSON data.

`example: <p>myUsernameHere</p>`

How can I remove the tags without removing the layout of the data?

Comment: Why would anyone be using Swift 2.3? The current version is Swift 4.1, with 4.2 just around the corner — and it's practically a different language at this point.

Comment: Sadly, I have no choice since it was just handed to me for a fix. As much as I want to upgrade it to 4.1, client doesn't want to.